# GC_FOR_ALLOC freed and Grow heap (frag case) messages with ScrollView

Tags: android, multithreading, memory, garbage-collection, scrollview

Whenever I simply instantiate `ScrollView` class like this:

```
ScrollView scrollView;
/** some code... **/
scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
```

I get these messages in LogCat in blue color:

```
D/dalvikvm(9245): JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (4096 bytes 2/0)
D/dalvikvm(9245): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 311K, 12% free 10749K/12112K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
D/dalvikvm(9245): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 11850K/13216K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
```

And this in green color:

```
I/dalvikvm-heap(9245): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.593MB for 1127536-byte allocation
```

I repeat, I just simply instantiate ScrollView class. I don't even do something with the object of this class and I still get these messages. Also I sometimes get this:

```
I/Choreographer(20731): Skipped X frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Where X stands for between 60 and 120...

The last message doesn't make sense at all, because the code doesn't even run in the main thread... It runs in a separate thread which I create inside a class which extends `Service` class.

Am I doing something wrong with that intantiation? And how to explain the last message???